# How to toggle fullscreen mode in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I was trying to make easy program in `pygame` but something doesn't work. After turning on program you can see full screen is red.
[SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ9b2.png)

Then you can press `F` to reduce screen.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDy2x.jpg)

After pressing `F` again screen should maximized but it is looking like that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEp61.jpg)
Anybody know the reason?

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

ScreenSizeMinx = pygame.display.Info().current_w / 2
ScreenSizeMiny = pygame.display.Info().current_h / 2

RED = (255, 0, 0)

Ekran = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
Ekran.fill(RED)
pygame.display.update()
FullScreen = True

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_f:
                if FullScreen:
                    Ekran = pygame.display.set_mode((ScreenSizeMinx, ScreenSizeMiny))
                    FullScreen = False
                else:
                    Ekran = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
                    FullScreen = True
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()

pygame.quit()
```

I was trying to repair it for about 2 hours but I can't find solution.

Comment: *"I have problem with my pygame code and I can't understand why"* is not an appropriate title for a question. The title should always briefly describe the problem. I have changed the tItle.

Answer (score 1):

Your application works fine, however you need to clear and update the display in the application loop:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

ScreenSizeMinx = pygame.display.Info().current_w / 2
ScreenSizeMiny = pygame.display.Info().current_h / 2

Ekran = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
FullScreen = True

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_f:
                if FullScreen:
                    Ekran = pygame.display.set_mode((ScreenSizeMinx, ScreenSizeMiny))
                    FullScreen = False
                else:
                    Ekran = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
                    FullScreen = True
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    Ekran.fill('red')                           # <---
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```